# Russian roulette - probability with spinning

Tags: probability

Typical Russian Roulette question, but I can't get my head around it:

1 person has a gun with 1 bullet (6 chambers). He spins the chambers before every attempt.

What are the odds that he WON'T survive 4 tries?

The solution should be 0.8024, but I have no idea how to get to that result.

Comment: Here's a different but related question... what is the probability that he *WILL* survive $4$ tries?  Here's a different but related question... what is the probability that you roll at least one $6$ in four throws of a fair six-sided die?  What is the probability that you roll no $6$'s in four throws of a fair six-sided die?  **Hint:** If two events $A$ and $B$ are independent then the probability of both happening is $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

Comment: That being said, I'm arriving at a number far different than $0.8024$, instead getting an answer closer to $0.5177$

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah, that's my problem: I'm not sure if I can thrust the textbook answer...

Comment: The only interpretation I can come up with that arrives at a number similar to $0.8024$ is where there are *two* bullets in six chambers (*or one bullet in three*) and four attempts.  It is possible this is a nearby exercise and you mistook the labels to the answer, or perhaps it was a typo or miscalculation on the author's part.  (*Sometimes after writing a question and a solution, authors can change their mind as to the wording of the question and not fix the solution to match the new wording*).

Comment: @JMoravitz only thing that comes to mind is four possible paths to death then I can fudge the numbers to get 76.5% roughly but that's about it.

Comment: As an aside, be very careful about not mixing up the words "odds" with "probability".  They are two related but technically different concepts.  The *probability* of rolling a six on a fair six-sided die is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The *odds* of doing so would however be $1:5$

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thank you for the reply, if you feel like grabbing some free points, feel free to post a quick answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For independent events $A,B$ (*such as each attempt at firing the gun after having spun the chamber*) we have the probability of both occurring as $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

> More generally if $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ are all mutually independent we have $Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_k)=Pr(A_1)Pr(A_2)\cdots Pr(A_k)$

*N.B.  It is not true in general that $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$.  This is only true for independent events and is false for dependent events.*

The answer of approximately $0.8024$ is the answer to a slightly different question.  That of if there happened to have been *two* bullets in the chambers instead of one where we still ask the probability of death within 4 tries.

> $1-(\frac{4}{6})^4=\frac{65}{81}\approx 0.802469$

For our question, we ask instead the related but different question of what is the probability that he *survives* four attempts.  That is, he needs to have missed the bullet four times in a row.  Each time he has a $\frac{5}{6}$ chance of landing on a chamber that doesn't contain a bullet.  Using what we know about independent events the probability of not getting a bullet four times in a row and thus surviving is...

> $(\frac{5}{6})^4$

So the probability that he doesn't survive is then $1$ minus that which is...

> $1-(\frac{5}{6})^4\approx 0.5177$